# Cant connect to mysql from python

Tags: python, mysql, iot, pubnub

I have this code which is receiving a call from pubnub, it takes in text and I want to store that text in a mysql database

```
class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        messageArray = message.dict
        print(messageArray['message']['sender'])
        cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

I keep receiving this error when trying to run my code

```
cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Any ideas on where the problem is?

Comment: Be sure of what db contains by printing it in console. Apparently, db has no "connection" object. I think that you probably want "db.cursor" instead "db.connection.cursor"

Comment: I checked the db and it printed: <flask_mysqldb.MySQL object at 0x000002B326C52EE0>

Comment: Ok, so it should looks like that : 
I put it in an answer because code formatting here is so bad

Answer (score 1):

Your code must looks like that :

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
db = MySQL(app)

# Your class/method where db.connection.cursor() is called

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run() # or app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Ive already established a connection with the database and run sql codes in other functions

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps below:

1. You will need to install mysql connector using the command below

`python -m pip install mysql-connector-python`

2. The below code is a simple connection you can use after installing the package

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

print(mydb)
```

Comment: I am using the Flask framework